# React and typescript with webpack typing issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to create an `asyncComponent` higher order component with TypeScript, but can't quite get the types right.

Essentially, this works in JS with webpack...

```
const Auth = asyncComponent(() =>
  require.ensure([], require => require("../auth/index").default, "auth_async"),
);
```

My `asyncComponent` is a higher order function that does the following...

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Component } from 'react';

export interface IAsyncComponentProps {}

export interface IAsyncComponentState {
  Component: typeof Component
}

interface IGetComponent {
  (): Promise<typeof Component>;
}

export default function asyncComponent (getComponent: IGetComponent) {
  let ComponentCache: typeof Component = null;

  return class AsyncComponent extends Component<IAsyncComponentProps, IAsyncComponentState> {
    state: {
      Component: typeof Component,
    };

    constructor(props: IAsyncComponentProps) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { Component: ComponentCache };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.state.Component) {
        getComponent().then((Component) => {
          ComponentCache = Component;

          this.setState({ Component });
        });
      }
    }
    render() {
      const { Component } = this.state;

      if (Component) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

But, I get an error when compiling it...

```
src/components/asyncComponent/index.tsx(40,27): error TS2322: Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<P, S>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode...'.
  Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<P>'.
src/index.ts(3,7): error TS1141: String literal expected.
11:06:50 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I will try my best to explain what went wrong and how it got solved in the latest release of typescript.

**Reason:**

The reason for change in behavior is that in 2.3, Similar to object literal expression which contains freshness flag, JSXAttributes are type-check too(this means that excess properties are not allowed)

**Solution Proposed:** - Refer the Reference link

1. Only contain explicitly attributes -> no excess properties allowed
2. Contain spread attributes (even with explicit attributes) -> 1.
   check type assignability (allow access properties) 2. for each
   explicit attributes check if the attribute name match the target
   name.

This issue is being apparently solved in 2.3.3 latest stable version and 2.4.0 dev as well.

Use `npm install typescript@next` for the `nightly build` that is `2.4.0 dev` or update the typescript version to latest stable(2.3.3)

Reference : [Issuse Tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15463)

Answer (score 2):

You example compiles fine without errors in TypeScript latest:

[image]

## More

- Update to `typescript@next`