# setState inside constructor not working properly: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to run the below code in React+Redux but am running into an unhandled

> exception 'NodeInvocationException: Cannot read property 'showText' of
>   null TypeError: Cannot read property 'showText' of null'

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';

import { Component } from 'react';

export interface BlinkState
{
    showText: boolean;
    text: '';
}

type BlinkProps = BlinkState;

class Blink extends React.Component<BlinkProps, BlinkState> {
    constructor(props: BlinkProps) {
        super(props);
        //this.state = { showText: true };

        this.setState({ showText: true, text: props.text });

        // Toggle the state every second
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(previousState => {
                return { showText: !previousState.showText };
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        let display = this.state.showText ? this.props.text : ' ';
        return <div>{ display }</div>;
    }
}


export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <Blink showText=false text='I love to blink' />
        </div>;
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to render the Blink copmonent with the props passed in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the basic thing, use of `constructor` and `setState`, use of `constructor` is to initialize the state value and use of `setState` is to update the state value, so using `setState` inside `constructor doesn't makes any sense.

Better way will be, initialise the state in constructor and to run the time use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, also don't forgot to stop the time before unmounting the component, to clear it use `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method.

Write the component like this:

```
class Blink extends React.Component<BlinkProps, BlinkState> {
    constructor(props: BlinkProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showText: false };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(previousState => {
                return { showText: !previousState.showText };
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }

    render() {
        let display = this.state.showText ? this.props.text : ' ';
        return <div>{ display }</div>;
    }
}
```

Working code:

```js
class Blink extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showText: true, text: props.text };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(prev => {
                return { showText: !prev.showText };
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimer(this.timer)
    }

    render() {
        let display = this.state.showText ? this.props.text : ' ';
        return <div>Hello { display }</div>;
    }
}

class Layout extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <Blink text='I love to blink' />
        </div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: ah ok I see, I'm still learning how this works. I'll keep in mind to use the constructor to set the initial state as you've shown.

Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem where the render on Layout for <blink/> doesn't work :(

Comment: I want to be able to do this:  <Blink text='I love to blink' /> but when I put that in the render function for the layout component I get an error (see my question)

Comment: ah no, I'm trying to make the Blink component render through my Layout component render function...

Comment: almost same just you need to pass the props value from parent, wait will edit the answer :)

Comment: That produces an error ' is not assignable to type 'InstrinsicAttribute & IntrinsicClassAttributes <Blink> & Readonly<{ children? ReactNode; }> & Rea... Types of property 'text' are incompatible Type "World" is not assiganble to type '""'' '

Comment: @tweetypi that error is related to typescript, check this link to solve your issue [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684686/react-and-typescript-with-webpack-typing-issue)

Comment: ah yep looks like I had to update typescript in VS to 2.5 and everything fell into place.

Answer (score 3):

You should not specify actions to be taken in the `constructor` or use `setState` there, `constructor` should be used to simply set an initial state.

Also you might need to update the `state text` since its being set based on props. Do it in the `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Also when you are using `setInterval`, make sure to `clearInterval` when the `componentUnmounts`

```
constructor(props: BlinkProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showText: true, text: props.text };

    }
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     this.setState({text: nextProps.text});
}
componentDidMount() {
      // Toggle the state every second
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(previousState => {
                return { showText: !previousState.showText };
            });
        }, 1000);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

Comment: ah ok thanks for the tips on how to set up the component correctly, I'm still learning and there's a lot of leeway afforded to making mistakes hehe.

Unfortunately I still can't work out how I can use the component like <Blink text='some text' /> without getting an error (see my question)

Comment: boolean value showText should be passed to component like `<Blink text='some text' showText={true} />`

Comment: When I try that I get the error "TS (Type '{ showText: ture; text: "World"; }' is not assignable to type 'InstrinsicAttribute & IntrinsicClassAttributes <Blink> & Readonly<{ children? ReactNode; }> & Rea...

Types of property 'text' are incompatible
Type "World" is not assiganble to type '""''